# Regression in R.. predict functions returns more rows that than the test dataset

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

My test dataset has only around 1200 rows but the predict function is giving way more than 3000 rows. Why is that so?

```
model_5 <- lm(precip~relative_humidity + dry_bulb_temp_f + wind_speed + station_pressure, data = train_noaa3)

str(predict(model_5, new_data = test_noaa3))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Question has been solved*

use the correct syntax for predict function:

predict(model, **newdata** = test_data)